# Moment js returns a negative timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I need to convert string in format 'MM-DD-YYYY' to unix timestamp

```
moment('06 13 2013').unix() - gives me 1371060000
```

However, when I try to convert 19** years, it gives negative timestamp

```
moment('06 13 1957').unix() - -396165600
```

Comment: That is the correct timestamp value.

Comment: That would happen to all request to dates prior to 01.01.1970 ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix that duplicate has little to do with the question, AFAICT

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca same symptom though..

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't a duplicate make :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the unix time starts at `01.01.1970 00:00:00`. Dates before that date will give negative timestamp since it is before `0`. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for more information on unix time.

It states in the first paragraph:

> Unix time (also known as POSIX time[citation needed] or UNIX Epoch time) is a system for describing a point in time. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), minus leap seconds.
>
> Every day is treated as if it contains exactly 86400 seconds, so leap seconds are to be subtracted since the epoch. It is used widely in Unix-like and many other operating systems and file formats. However, Unix time is not a true representation of UTC, as a leap second in UTC shares the same Unix time as the second which came before it. Unix time may be checked on most Unix systems by typing date +%s on the command line.

You can also play around with different dates or timestamps and convert them to one another [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).